# Mirroring Server Setup

Tags: mac-osx, installation, cloning

My boss has purchased 4 Mac mini servers, and I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to mirror their installations, meaning whatever is installed on one can be mirrored to the rest.

I was hoping that there would be a way to do this as they will be identical servers in seperate locations.

Comment: You mean a kickstart capability?

Answer (score 1):

If the servers are identical, and you want to save time initially configuring it, you can setup only one server, and then use Clonezilla to clone to others

See: http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I was looking for thanks!